# Math Symbols Palette?

Tags: macros, symbols

I'm using TeXworks version 0.4.3 r857 (MiKTeX 2.9) in Windows 7.

Usually I use TeXShop on the Mac, but my Mac G5 is in need of repair. So now on the Windows side I'm wondering if there is an equivalent for the palette full of oft-used math symbols. Also, what about macros for common typographical edits? Do such things exist or is one forced to type in all the math symbols and typographical commands by hand?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) (see also the [GUI snapshot](http://www.texniccenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/gui.png))

Comment: ... or [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/snap.html) (Check the section _GUI Page Control (TeX Symbols)_)

Comment: You can try Texstudio, which has palettes for symbols and commands.

Comment: Not in TeXworks, but as mentioned there are several other editors providing this. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides for a big list of alternative editors, some of which has this feature.

Comment: Use whatever editor you like -- as for IDEs, I like TeXlipse -- and look up symbols with [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question, since DeTeXify isn't really a reasonable replacement for a GUI palette.

Comment: @AlanMunn: True, it's a lot better. I can draw the symbol instead of looking for it in some palette. Or what feature of palletes do you have in mind? (FWIW, you can copy the commands from there to your editor, but I think trying to shortcut typing when using LaTeX is ill-advised at best.)

Comment: The TeXShop palette is organized into panels thematically so you can find things very fast, certainly much faster than you can draw it. Furthermore, it's in the editor, not in your browser, so you don't need to switch, and clicking on a symbol will insert the code directly into your source.  Personally I never use it, but I think for new users it's quite helpful. Obviously once you know most of the symbols you use, you will start typing them directly anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there are editors with such GUIs.

---

1. Winedt:

[image]

You have to press the `\Sigma` button (shown in red rectangle in picture) to open the math palette. It has also the AMS symbols etc as you can see from the list (inside green rectangle). Caveat: It is *shareware*.

---

2. Texmaker:

[image]

---

3. Texstudio:

[image]

In both TeXmaker and TeXstudio, these palettes can be activated from the buttons available in the sidebar.

---

4. TeXnicCenter:

[image]

You can activate the toolbars by View → Toolbars as in the picture.

---

5. Kile (can be installed in windows too :-)...)

[image]

Comment: Ah! Now how do I correct the enumeration?

Comment: See my edit! (HTML comment character is your friend.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks Alan. I tried it but with wrong number of dashes. :-(. Some how I keep forgetting these things.

Answer (score 1):

Check out:
[https://www.caam.rice.edu/~heinken/latex/symbols.pdf](https://www.caam.rice.edu/%7Eheinken/latex/symbols.pdf)
This is a pdf document listing all mathematical symbols with Latex coding.
Nice document to have for reference.