# Add menu button in notepad++ to insert math symbols for use with latex

Tags: math-mode, symbols, editors

As in the title, I'm looking for a menu button (or similar) for Notepad++ that shows (mathematical) symbols to insert them (such as `\Rightarrow`, integration symbol, greek letters …) into the `.tex` document as in other environments (IIRC emacs with `auctex`)

I couldn't find any similar questions/answers, so any answer is highly appreciated.
Sorry if it's a duplicate.

cheers

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question might be a duplicate, but it's more likely off-topic

Comment: This sounds like a feature request to the maintainers of N++ rather than a question about TeX…

Comment: @Sigur Questions regarding LaTeX editors are on-topic, isn't it? This is in line wit *How to install Auctex in Emacs*. It is near 400 questions under the tag [emacs]. It is much better to answer the question: *No, I do not know if there is such a menubar for Notepad++*. There is no conseptual different between a plugin for Notepad++, Vim or Emacs.

Comment: The problem is that: **(1)** inserting pre-defined text is not a LaTeX-specific feature; **(2)** Notepad++ is not a LaTeX-specific editor (like TeXworks), **(3)** neither a LaTeX-specific plugin is involved (like LaTeX-suite for VIM), **(4)** Notepad++ doesn't seem to have any programming layer directly accessible, you hhave to re-compile the program, which IMHO indeed makes it a feature request. Without the intention to sound harsh, I don't think that this question makes any sense on this site. Whether it makes sense on e.g. [SU]? I don't know, because of Point (4).

Comment: @semml, are you asking for something like screenshots in [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142009/22492), answer but for notepad++?

Comment: @Sveinung thank you, i'm using n++ for many things so i didn't want to get another environment for latex, but i guess i might have to do that

Comment: @tohecz i see your points, thank you for clearing things up, never thought about my question in that way(s)

Comment: @Pouya yes, exactly

Comment: @tohecz That do not thinks you have to recompile Notepadd++ to make a plug-in. Notepad++ has a plugin interface well documented and it exist many of plugins, see [this link](http://npp-wiki.tuxfamily.org./index.php?title=Plugin_Development). Unfortunately no LeTeX plug-in but a good description how to compile latex documents from Notepad++. So it does not seems to be a conceptual difference from a plug-in for Notepad and a Lisp module for Emacs. Conclusion: The question should be accepted as on topic.

Comment: @SeanAllred No, it is a question if it exists a plug in for Notepad++ with this features.

Comment: @tohecz And Notepad++ has a lexer and a language module recognising tex-files for colour coding latex source files. It has command parameter to integrate forward and backward searching in PDF-files (tightly integrated with Sumatra PDF). So feature by feature, it is comparable with Texwork, after a little tweaking.

Comment: Since it boils down to inserting predefined text, I do believe this would be on-topic on SuperUser as @tohecz suggests. I would counter the editor argument by saying: a question such 'how can I get Word to recognize more TeX symbols in the equation editor' would be decidedly off-topic. What is the difference?

Comment: @Sveinung I would say that when you begin asking about *professional* editors, such as emacs or vim, you are rather asking a question about their TeX-specific packages, not the general editor itself (which would also be off-topic). While this is asking how to add TeX-oriented features to n++, it is a question about n++ – *not* TeX or TeX programs.

Comment: @SeanAllred So you are one of the true believers ... Well, no idea to waste time discussing alternatives with you. Like writer2latex and friends are on topic here, I would argue that questions regarding similar extensions to Word are on topic. But I would agree that how to add features to Auctex or a vim tex modules, are off topic.